# Query of max order within 10 year from the first recorded order date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am supposed to retrieve the max order from within 10 years of the first recorded order date.  I tried the following query:

```
SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE FROM CUSTOMERS C
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS O ON C.ORDER_ID = O.ID
    WHERE O.PRICE = (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM (SELECT * FROM ORDERS O2 WHERE O2.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN MIN(O2.ORDER_DATE) AND DATEADD(year, 10, MIN(O2.ORDER_DATE))))
```

but it gives the error of:

> not derivable from table.

Could somebody help to point out my mistake?

Comment: You might use a Having clause to specify the condition for selecting the max price in the subquery.

Comment: Please include some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson could you please elaborate?

Comment: @PM sorry but this is a HackerRank test question thus I am not allowed to disclose the details

Comment: Then invent your own sample data and provide the desired result based on it.

Comment: Your `join` conditions look broken.  I haven't seen a customers table with an order id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you use `MIN(O2.ORDER_DATE)` without deriving it from a query.
Also there is no need for `BETWEEN` because all you need is the order date to be before the minimum date + 10 years.
You can get the max price by sorting the result of the query descending and keeping only the 1st row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 C.NAME, O.PRICE 
FROM CUSTOMERS C INNER JOIN ORDERS O 
ON C.ORDER_ID = O.ID
WHERE O.ORDER_DATE <= DATEADD(year, 10, (SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS))
ORDER BY O.PRICE DESC
```

I assume that you use SQL Server, this is why I use `TOP 1`.

Comment: many thanks! could you also add O.PRICE = MAX(PRICE) version?  I wish to check that other than the MIN(O2.ORDER_DATE) mistake my solution is correct

Comment: The MAX(PRICE) version is less efficient and more complicated: `SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE 
FROM CUSTOMERS C INNER JOIN ORDERS O 
ON C.ORDER_ID = O.ID
WHERE O.ORDER_DATE <= DATEADD(year, 10, (SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS))
AND O.PRICE = (
  SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM ORDERS
  WHERE ORDER_DATE <= DATEADD(year, 10, (SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS))
)`

Comment: yeah, actually I was thinking of using some sort of window function (as given in the answer below) to filter out the orders that are more than 10 years from the first order date

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions!

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             max(price) over (partition by customer_id) as max_price
      from (select o.*,
                   min(order_date) over (partition by o.customer_id) as first_order_date
            from orders o
           ) o
      where order_date < dateadd(year, 10, first_order_date)
     ) o
where price = max_price;
```

I will let you join back to the customer table to get the name and other customer information that you might want.

This assumes that `orders` has a `customer_id` column of some sort, which is normally how such tables are set up.

Comment: many thanks! my original solution is sort of following this direction to filter out the orders that are more than 10 years from the first order date but did not work out

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE VIEW temp_order AS
    (SELECT PRICE, ID FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDER_DATE <= DATE_ADD((SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS), INTERVAL 10 YEAR));
    SELECT C.NAME, PRICE 
    FROM CUSTOMERS C JOIN 
    temp_order ON C.ORDER_ID = temp_order.ID 
    WHERE PRICE = (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM temp_order);
```